# how do i convert a tf.Variable to numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

How could I convert a `tf.Variable` to a numpy array?

```py
var1 = tf.Variable(4.0)
```

I want to get `[4.0]`

Comment: Welcome. It would be great if you could include the code that you tried to achieve your objective.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call [**`.numpy()`**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L1042-L1067) on the Tensor object.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(4.0)
b = tf.Variable([4.0])
c = tf.Variable([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

a.numpy()
# 4.0

b.numpy()
# array([4.], dtype=float32)

c.numpy()
# array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]], dtype=int32)
```

See [Customization basics: tensors and operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics) for more. Also as stated in the docs

> Numpy array may share memory with the Tensor object. Any changes to one may be reflected in the other.

---

If Eager Execution is disabled, you can build a graph and then run it through `tf.compat.v1.Session`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(4.0)
b = tf.Variable([4.0])
c = tf.Variable([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

a.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())
# 4.0
```